# Как получить значения внутреннего массива

Tags: java, json

Не могу понять как правильно распарсить JSON ответ от сервера

```
 { "head": {},
      "def": [
         { "text": "time", "pos": "noun",
           "tr": [
              { "text": "время", "pos": "существительное",
                "syn": [
                   { "text": "раз" },
                   { "text": "тайм" }
                ],
                "mean": [
                   { "text": "timing" },
                   { "text": "fold" },
                   { "text": "half"}
                ],
                "ex" : [
                   { "text": "prehistoric time",
                     "tr": [
                        { "text": "доисторическое время" }
                     ]
                   },
                   { "text": "hundredth time",
                     "tr": [
                        { "text": "сотый раз" }
                     ]
                   },
                   { "text": "time-slot",
                     "tr": [
                        { "text": "тайм-слот" }
                     ]
                   }
                ]
              }
```

Comment: В следующий раз хотя бы валидные данные приводите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается так:

1. Берём либу Gson `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'`
2. Пользуем сайт типа [этого](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) для преобразования `JSON` в `Java` классы.
3. Парсим `JSON` в `Java` классы либой из п.1 примерно так:

```
String jsonString = ...;
Example result = new Gson.Builder().build().fromJson(jsonString, Example.class);
```

В итоге вся инфа у вас будет в переменной result и к ней легко и просто обращаться.