# Помогите придумать парсер

Tags: java

Помогите придумать парсер для строк такого типа

```
{"id":"663860","values":["A","Agilent Technologies Inc","68.07","+0.05","chg","0.07","","21.91B","NYSE","663860","A"]},

{"id":"1053115004664670","values":["AA","Alcoa Corp","47.20","-0.50","chr","-1.05","","8.73B","NYSE","1053115004664670","AA"]},

{"id":"380935611399505","values":["AAAP","Advanced Accelerator Application SA (ADR)","80.97","-0.06","chr","-0.07","","3.58B","NASDAQ","380935611399505","AAAP"]},

{"id":"658890","values":["AABA","Altaba Inc","70.41","-0.18","chr","-0.25","","62.44B","NASDAQ","658890","AABA"]},
```

Нужно вытащить из каждой строки 
- значение которое идет после квадратный скобок (A, AA, AAAP, AABA)
- значение, которое идет в кавычках после "chr" (0.07, -1.05, -0.07, -0.25)
- значение через "," после того что было выше (21.91B, 8.73B, 3.58B, 62.44B)

Comment: Это, вроде, JSON. Для него есть множество библиотек. Можете, например, взять гугловое решение `Gson`

Comment: Это ж JSON, пробовали с ним как с JSON работать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  мне кажется надо совсем совсем каноничный ответ сделать по парсингу json в java... я предложил дубликат выше. но он не совсем полный

Comment: Возможно ещё вот это подойдёт: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644130/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/644144#644144

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, надо бы такой вопрос для заворачивания дублей сделать) Вот бы ещё найти энтузиаста................. =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ будет время, займусь

Comment: @GenCloud, было бы круто)

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ так что собственно требуется, ман на мете по сериализации/десериализации Json строки стандартными средствами и апи?

Comment: @GenCloud, лучше тут, чем на мете) Думаю, было бы круто кратко описать там что есть этот самый JSON, привести примеры его парсинга стандартными средствами (в андроиде, вроде, встроенный есть, например) и сторонними либами с преобразованием в Java-классы. Ну и помянуть, что регулярки тут не к месту. В общем так бы надо оформить, чтобы можно было много вопросов закрывать дублем на этот новый)

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ нашаманим что-нибудь

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливаем апи Gson. 
Читаем объект -> `Gson#fromGson(path_to_file, ObjectInfo.class)`

***ObjectInfo.class***

```
public class ObjectInfo implements Serializable{
   public long id;

   public List<String> values;
       //get;set
   }
```

Далее вытаскиваем из собранного листа начиная с 5 элемента (если Вы имеете четкое расположение элементов в каждом объекте)